# Fatal error: Call to a member function is_type() woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on `Woocommerce` with `Wordpress V 4.5`. I am getting below error only for one product rest products are working fine.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_type() on a non-object in
>   /home/example/public_html/wp-content/themes/dss/woocommerce/cart/cart-item-data.php
>   on line 35

[image]